# iOS form-control placeholder vertical alignment

Tags: ios, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm currently developing an Angular 4 web application using Bootstrap 3 in which i have several text and select inputs. Select inputs are not a problem, they're working correctly, but in text input fields i have a problem with placeholders.

My input code is like this (just a standard input):

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
```

I can see it as it's supposed to be in Chrome/Firefox in desktop and several Android devices with different versions, but in iOS 11+ devices (iPhone 6S,8,8 Plus,X) with different browsers it looks like the image:

[image]

If i remove the "form-control" class from the email field it looks like this image:

[image]

Does anybody knows a solution which doesn't involve removing "form-control" and changes styles in all text input fields in my app or change the webkit placeholder css position (as this solution could make the web style change in several browsers and not just in Safari)?

Answer (score 2):

I can't see imgur pictures (corporate proxy), but if the vertical align of an input is your issue, the solution is using the `line-height` property. You can either fix the value, or get the height of the input and set the value dynamically.

Here is an example with a rather large input.

```css
input.form-control {
  margin: 24px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
```

Comment: This could be a solution, but i'm looking for a solution that not involves modify the size of all input text fields in the web app

Comment: I'm not telling you to change the size of the input ... You should change the size of the line-height. I sepcifically stated that I changed the size to show you that it works.